# How to use polymorphism to hide properties of an interface?

Tags: typescript, linq, polymorphism

I am building this Type safe LINQ problem in TypeScript as part of a school project. The whole project description can be found here: https://github.com/hogeschool/Software-Engineering-Minor/blob/master/Projects/project2%20-%20mini%20typesafe%20LINQ%20to%20SQL.md

As part of the project there is a constraint that the order of the operators matter. In my case the `Select` operator should be the only possible and first operation to perform. After the first select the other operators become visible: `Include`, `Where`, `OrderBy` and `GroupBy`.

So you should not be able to group, filter or sort when the there is nothing selected.

I thought of splitting my code into parts, I have to interfaces one called `Table` which contains the data where the operators are performed on and `LazyTable` which only holds a chain of functions to be applied on the data in a later stadium of the program.

But I run into some trouble when it comes to the dependency from `LazyTable` on `Table`, because `LazyTable` simply uses the operations of `Table`.

```
interface Table<T, U> {
    data: Data<T, U>
    Select: () => Table
    Include: () => Table
    Where: () => Table
    OrderBy: () => Table
    GroupBy: () => Table
    toList: () => List
}

interface LazyTable<T, U> {
    query: Query<T1, U1, T2, U2>
    Select: () => LazyTable
    Include: () => LazyTable
    Where: () => LazyTable
    OrderBy: () => LazyTable
    GroupBy: () => LazyTable
    apply: (data) => Table 
}
```

The current situation is that I can initialize an instance of `Table` or `LazyTable` and call their methods:

```
users.Select("name", "email", "age").Include("Products", q => q.Select("price", "name", "quantity").Where("price", GreaterThan(100))).OrderBy("age", "DESC")
```

I want this to happen in such a way that calling:

```
users.Where()
users.Include()
users.OrderBy()
users.GroupBy()
```

Is not possible before calling `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Select` return a different interface, which contains the additional methods, and don't include them in the original `Table` interface. That's I think the only reasonable approach.

What you actually mean is not forbidding calling `table.Where` before calling `table.Select`, but just forbidding calling `table.Where` altogether. The only object on which you can call `Where` is the result of calling `table.Select`, right? So make this a different interface.